# NullPointerException when trying to open a .html file with Vaadin Designer 7

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, vaadin

im using Eclipse 2018_09 with Vaadin 8. I just created a clean Vaadin Project "myapplication" straight forward. When i create a Vaadin Designer File, "testdesigne.html" and try to open it, the designer is crashing and the file will be closed. It first trys to load the view and crashes after ~5 sec.

When i open the Eclipse Error Log View, i can see following 2 Problems:

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".

---

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.views.HierarchyOutlineView.dispose(HierarchyOutlineView.java:470)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditorPart.dispose(VaadinEditorPart.java:422)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$4.run(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1014)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45) at
> org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.disposePart(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1010)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.dispose(MultiPageEditorPart.java:507)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditor.dispose(VaadinEditor.java:328)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.invalidate(CompatibilityPart.java:264)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.destroy(CompatibilityPart.java:424)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.uninject(InjectorImpl.java:200)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.uninject(Requestor.java:175)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:87)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:114)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.removeListenersTo(EclipseContext.java:492)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.uninject(ContextInjectionFactory.java:175)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:967)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$1(PartRenderingEngine.java:886)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:881)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45) at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:865)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.subscribeTopicToBeRendered(PartRenderingEngine.java:186)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.di.internal.extensions.EventObjectSupplier$DIEventHandler.handleEvent(EventObjectSupplier.java:91)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:204)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:199)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:138)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:81)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:42)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
> at
> org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.UIElementImpl.setToBeRendered(UIElementImpl.java:307)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1381)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.hidePart(WorkbenchPage.java:1591)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.hidePart(WorkbenchPage.java:1543)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.closeEditors(WorkbenchPage.java:1513)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.closeEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:1637)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditor.closeEditor(VaadinEditor.java:897)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditor.closeDesignInNewerProjectAndNotifyUser(VaadinEditor.java:876)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditor.validateDesignFileInteractive(VaadinEditor.java:816)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditorPart$2$1.run(VaadinEditorPart.java:185)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40) at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.FakeComposite.flushAsyncQueue(FakeComposite.java:166)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.FakeComposite.flushAsyncQueue(FakeComposite.java:140)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.FakeComposite.setLayoutDeferred(FakeComposite.java:127)
> at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredLayouts(Display.java:3982)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3554)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:628) at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659) at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595) at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)

---

Unhandled event loop exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSite.getShell(PartSite.java:477) at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditor.openDesigner2InstallWarning(VaadinEditor.java:886)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditor.closeDesignInNewerProjectAndNotifyUser(VaadinEditor.java:878)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditor.validateDesignFileInteractive(VaadinEditor.java:816)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditorPart$2$1.run(VaadinEditorPart.java:185)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40) at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.FakeComposite.flushAsyncQueue(FakeComposite.java:166)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.FakeComposite.flushAsyncQueue(FakeComposite.java:140)
> at
> com.vaadin.designer.eclipse.editors.FakeComposite.setLayoutDeferred(FakeComposite.java:127)
> at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredLayouts(Display.java:3982)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3554)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:628) at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659) at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595) at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)

anyone any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Eclipse 2018-09 has been outdated for a long time and Stack Overflow is not about retrocomputing for reasons. If you find bugs that can be reproduced in the current version, make sure they have been reported. The log snippets are hard to read without the line breaks that get lost by formatting it as quote instead of as code snippets. There is `internal` code involved, so it might be that the Vaadin plugin of the version you have does not work with this outdated version of Eclipse. But that's hard to tell since the log is also incomplete and it's unclear what you mean by _crashing_.

Comment: it works with Eclipse Neon so i asume that it has to work with 2018-09 too. I will try the latest version of Eclipse. The log snippets are all i have cause the error log view doesnt show more. 

Crashing, it closes the window, the Designer-Editor Window.

Comment: Use also the latest version of the Designer. To get a minimal log, delete the log, reproduce the issue and close Eclipse. Show the whole minimal log, not only snippets of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Vaadin **Designer 2** for Vaadin 8.